# Changing alpha value on portions of the frame with a texture

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm working on a 2D painting app using OpenGL. The part I'm struggling with, as other have on stack overflow, is the eraser capability. This is an OS X application using OpenGL 3.2.

Others have suggested using the Stencil Buffer, which I've implemented. But, as far as I can understand, the stencil buffer is a hard mask -- either Pass or Fail -- without any ability to handle alpha levels. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

The paint strokes are created by applying a texture along a path of points.  My fragment shader for the brush looks like this. I'm applying a color to the black & alpha brush texture.

```
uniform sampler2D tex;
uniform vec4 color;
out vec4 outColor;

void main() {
    outColor = mix( vec4(color.rgb,0), vec4(color.rgb,1), texture(tex,gl_PointCoord));
}
```

In my ideal world, the eraser would just update the alpha values of the the frame, making pixels less visible according to the erase texture. It seems like this should be possible using glBlendFunc(), but I've tried a bunch of combinations and nothing works.

My brush texture is something like this. Shown against a gray background here, but the actual PNG is just black and alpha.

[image: Screenshot 1]

Using the following blend functions:

Brush painting:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Erase painting:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_DST_COLOR, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

I get this effect, obviously not what I want. I've tried every recommended combination of glBlenFunc I've found on SO and nothing has given me the desired result. What am I missing?

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: I know it would be easy to just paint the background color as the "erase," but that would not work for multiple layers and transparency.

Comment: For all intents and purposes, the stencil buffer is pass/fail. Newer hardware lets you read it from shaders and that would allow you 256 values to do whatever you wanted with. But this is really all down to blending anyway - I _think_ what you actually want is [`glBlendFuncSeparate (...)`](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glBlendFuncSeparate) judging by _"In my ideal world, the eraser would just update the alpha values of the the frame"_. If you separate the RGB and A blend functions you can leave RGB untouched while blending A.

Comment: The thing is, though... updating the alpha values in the framebuffer is not going to affect the blending of your brush paint, because the framebuffer is the _destination_ and not the _source_. Your other blend function relies only on source alpha.

Comment: The brush paint is drawn before the erase strokes, so should it matter what the brush paint blending is?Unless I'm misunderstanding how the color buffer works. Logically, brush strokes that come AFTER erase strokes happen shouldn't be affected by the erase stroke.

Comment: Someone asking a related OpenGL question posed it this way: "If source RGBA is (r2, g2, b2, a2) and destination is (r1, g1, b1, a1). I want the final value to be (r1, g1, b1, a2). How do I achieve this?"

Comment: That particular operation can be handled using `glBlendFuncSeparate (GL_ZERO, GL_ONE, GL_ONE, GL_ZERO)`.  RGB = rgb2 * 0  +  rgb1 * 1, A = a2 * 1  +  a1 * 0. And that _might_ be useful, if you use the destination alpha in a later pass for something like compositing, but I don't know if you do that here?

Comment: Thanks for the insight. My intended outcome is that the document would have separate layers (like Photoshop), and yes, those layers would be composited together along with a background layer.

Comment: Oh, then that ought to work. Assuming this erase operation is its own layer, then you would use a blend function like `GL_ZERO, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA` during composition. That will throw out the eraser's RGB and modulate the layer you're blending with by the eraser's alpha channel.

Comment: We're getting close! https://www.dropbox.com/s/jzowsc4oa5ppjfi/Screenshot%202015-03-10%2015.51.56.png?dl=0

Comment: The only issue is some black artifacts around the part of the line that was erased. The brush paint is using glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA), the erase is using glBlendFuncSeparate(GL_ZERO, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ZERO, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);, and the final comp is using glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

Comment: I have initially cleared the Color Buffer with  glClearColor(1,1,1,0.0); so it is filled with transparency.

Comment: Those black artifacts can probably be avoided if you used pre-multiplied alpha. Your final composition would be `GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA`. You'd have to multiply RGB by A in your fragment shader before doing the blending for that stage.

Comment: That's making sense! That got rid of the black artifacts, but now my paint has white artifacts, that I can't shake. https://www.dropbox.com/s/8pklc7tnvz9o0qq/Screenshot%202015-03-10%2017.06.17.png?dl=0

Comment: This is now fixed, the fix for the white artifacts was to set my color buffer on my layer to glClearColor(0,0,0,0.0). Previously I had 1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0

Answer (score 1):

The fix was to use the blending function GL_ZERO, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA. I render the brush paint and erase strokes to a texture, and then render that texture to my frame buffer. The fix for the white outlines was to set my first pass render to glClearColor(0,0,0,1)